# Haskell couldn't match expected type float with actual type 'a'

Tags: haskell, types, type-mismatch

I have run into a problem when trying to add 2 parts of a tuple together

Function Type:

```
close :: (Floating a, Ord a) => (a,a) -> (a,a) -> Float
```

Function definition:

```
close y x = sqrt (((fromIntegral(snd x) - fromIntegral(snd y))^2) + ((fromIntegral(fst x) - fromIntegral(fst y)^2)))
```

On feeding the function a y tuple of format ( , ) and a x tuple of format ( , ) it should calculate the distance between two coordinates. 
However on launch I get an error of:

```
Couldn't match expected type 'Float' with actual type 'a'
a is a rigid type variable bound by...
```

I do understand why the problem is arising, but I have no idea how to fix it

Comment: You mention `Floating a` in type definition and then feed `fromIntegral` in the function with the same `a` type which is supposed to belong `Integral` type class... which is a conflict.

Comment: You need a function `Floating a => a -> Float` to produce the result. I would expect `close :: Floating a => (a,a) -> (a,a) -> a`, or `close :: (Integral a, Floating b) => (a,a) -> (a,a) -> b`. Where do `Ord` and `Float` come from?

Comment: @molbdnilo maybe he wants a concrete `Float` from the output?

Comment: @molbdnilo yes, I have no idea why i had float.... I think I just didnt realise that I can use a as the ambiguous for float

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your type is wrong. As Redu mentions in the comments, you have a type under typeclass `Floating` and are calling `fromIntegral` on it.

```
Prelude> :t fromIntegral
fromIntegral :: (Num b, Integral a) => a -> b
```

You can't have a `Floating` `Integral`, so this fails. Your type instead should be:

```
close :: Integral a => (a, a) -> (a, a) -> Float
```

Note that you also don't need as many `fromIntegral` calls, since `(^)` operates on `(Num a, Integral b) => a -> b -> a`, any number can be the base. The only operation that matters is `sqrt` which requires a `Floating a`.

```
close :: Integral a => (a, a) -> (a, a) -> Float
close (x1, y1) (x2, y2) = sqrt . fromIntegral $ squaredDistance where
  squaredDistance = (x1 - x2) ^ 2 + (y1 - y2) ^ 2
```

Answer (score 0):

One technique to help you debug this would be to comment out your type signature and ask the system what the type is. In ghci, that'll be `:t close`.

Comment: gives me
   'Floating a => (a,a) -> (a,a) -> a'

Comment: which is basically what I had as my type

Comment: @MaxUmarovs Your definition of `close` does not have that type, but `(Floating a1, Integral b, Integral b1, Integral a, Integral a2) => (a2, b1) -> (a, b) -> a1`.

Comment: @MaxUmarovs you missed the part where he said to comment out your type signature.